# In what package is now located the .csrf() method in Spring 5?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, csrf

I am trying to write an IT.

```
mockMvc.perform( post( "/my_endpoint" )
            .contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
            .header("Authorization", my_credentials)
            .with(csrf())
            .content( jsonPayload )
                )
            .andExpect( status().isOk() );
```

I need to import the `csrf()` static method, but the package where usually was founded **(org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors...)** no longer exists.

Some fresh idea on how can I write a csrf protection to avoid a `403` on the test?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To use the Spring Security test support, you must include ***spring-security-test-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar*** as a dependency of your project.
And give a try below:-

```
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProce ssors.*;

mvc.perform(post("/").with(csrf()))
```

or,

```
mvc.perform(post("/").with(csrf().asHeader()))
```

or,

```
mvc.perform(post("/").with(csrf().useInvalidToken()))
```

Comment: The package test under security does not exists anymore, that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as follows

```
csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on the Spring Reactive. **Spring Boot :2.6.1**

Add below entry in build.gradle

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
```

And then, csrf() method will be available from below import

```
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.reactive.server.SecurityMockServerConfigurers.csrf;
```